# array for trader_sma function from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm not programer but I know little bit of php and I can write some simple scripts. I created script which is downloading prices of all coins from one exchange every 1 min (by cron job) to my database. Now I want to calculate EMA, SMA, MACD and other TA indicators. Until now I can select 5 last prices of coin but I can not get them in indexed array for trader_sma function. I'm stuck at this point. Can you help me?

```
$sql = "SELECT `lastPrice` FROM `$table` WHERE `symbol` = '$symbol' AND import_nr > $from_import_nr";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM)) {    // 
 $lastPrice = $row[0];
 echo $lastPrice;
        }
}

/*
I get prices but not in correct format
I'm geting this 0.000356060.000355710.000356070.000356060.00035607
but I need something like this for trader_sma function
$price_for_sma = array (0.00035606, 0.00035571, 0.00035607, 0.00035606, 0.00035607);
*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting `$lastPrice` each time, just dynamically append `[]` each item from `$row[0]` to your new array:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
    $price_for_sma[] = $row[0];
}
```

Or access the `0` index of the function return like this:

```
while($price_for_sma[] = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)[0]) {}
```

Assuming `$price_for_sma` has not been defined as a string or non-array before the loop.  If so, choose a different name or do `$price_for_sma = [];` directly before the loop.  This might be best practice anyway.

Comment: With this I'm getting Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings @AbraCadaver

Comment: _With this_ What is **this**? The code I posted won't give that, you're not trying to `echo $lastPrice[]` are you?

Comment: Neither will do that and you don't mention if you're using the first loop or second.

Comment: I see, you've defined `$lastPrice` as a string somewhere before the loop.  Change it, I'm editing.

Comment: Yes, one step before I'm showing id, symbol and lastPrice as a string. If I comment out that part - I dont get error and I get nice result. Thank you!